# UI Automation's AutomationId inconsistency on different versions of windows

Tags: .net, windows, automation, ui-automation, uia

I'm working on automating an application using UI Automation framework (.net 4.6.1).

When inspecting the application using `Visual UI Automation Verify` i'm able to see the value of `AutomationId` properties.

I have written a small automation script in C# (wpf)

When I execute my automation script on windows 7, all works fine.

When I try it on windows 10, all the AutomationId values are string empty.

Sample code:

```
AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst (
  TreeScope.Descendants, 
  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, myAutomationId)
);
```

This sample returns null, because it cannot find an element with `myAutomationId` value, when I explored all the children of `AutomationElement.RootElement` I found that the AutomationId values are empty (unlike what i see on `Visual UI Automation Verify`, and unlike what i get when running on windows 7)

Is there something i'm missing about `AutomationId` properties? or about how 
UI Automation framework runs on windows 10?

**Edit:**

I have noticed that when I loop through the child elements, I have found that some of them have an AutomationId that has a value of the NativeWindowHandle.. why is that??

**Edit 2:**

I have tried a very wide range of UI Automation dlls with multiple versions, none of was able to even find the application on windows 10.

Same thing goes for `TestStack.White` (doesn't work on windows 7 either).

Answer (score 1):

The UIA which works fine is **UIAutomationClient.dll**  (+ UIAutomationTypes.dll if needed)

It uses Automation interfaces directly :

```
IUIAutomation uiautomation = new CUIAutomation();
```

and so on...